# Pegar componentes que estão dentro de um arquivo xhtml

Tags: java, html, primefaces

Em um um código fonte facelets (xhtml) do primefaces, quero extrair todas as tags `<p:inputText>`. Depois disso, quero pegar o atributo `label`. Teria como realizar isso? Lembrando que os componentes teram valores preenchidos diferentes, e posso colocar outras tags do primefaces como `outputlabel` ou `div`.

Comment: Macario, você tem um código fonte facelets (xhtml) e quer extrair determinadas tags, é isso?

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly isso ai! Para ser mais preciso, queria extrair as tags de determinados componentes para pegar seus labels e gerar um arquivo properties. Entende?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa de um parser. Enquanto o JDK possui o [DocumentParser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/parser/DocumentParser.html), ele é legado e atrelado as APIs do Swing.

Minha recomendação seria o [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)

```
// Trate exceções no código real
File input = new File("/tmp/input.xhtml");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8");
Elements labels = doc.select("p|inputText[label]");
// todos os inputs que possuem um label
for (Element label : labels) {
   String sLabel = label.attr("label"); 
   System.out.println("Label: " + sLabel);
}
```

Estou assumindo que você vai extrair os labels diretamente do código Facelets, mas se precisar extrair do html gerado é só adaptar o código de acordo.

Comment: Neste trecho o que foi usado? Regex? `doc.select("p|inputText[label]")`

Comment: Não, é uma [sintaxe de select](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) similar a do jQuery. Veja a [Documentação](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/) do Jsoup. Ela procura por todas as tags `inputText` com o namespace `p` e que contenham um atributo `label`.

Comment: Só mais uma dúvida, eu não tenho 100% certeza porque são 80 páginas xhtml que quero fazer isso, quais são ao todo, os elementos que usam label, que na verdade seguem um padrão deste tipo `#{lbl['LABEL.CHECKLIST.ITEMDEVERIFICACAO']}`, todos tem isso `#{lbl['']}`.

Comment: Macario, você pode usar os métodos das classes [Element](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html) e [Attributes](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Attributes.html) para iterar os atributos dos elementos e filtrar apenas aqueles que comecem com `#{lbl['` (por exemplo), mas esse é um processamento bem caro (verificar todas as tags e cada elemento de cada tag), quanto melhor você conseguir filtrar os elementos melhor.

Comment: Cara, consegui, muito doido! `Elements labels = doc.select("[label*=#]");`

Comment: Infelizmente algumas tags como `h:inputText` não foram pegas

Comment: Não entendi, porque quando eu mando selecionar é os elementos que `label*=#`, deveria trazer todos não?

Comment: Deu erro...Não pode fazer o parse

Comment: vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13023/discussion-between-anthony-accioly-and-macario1983)